# How do I remove subfolders an image's URL using ".htaccess"?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

How do I remove subfolders names from URL?

For example:

1. mywebsite.com/wp-contents/uploads/2019/02/image.jpg
2. mywebsite.com/wp-contents/uploads/user/demo/2019/02/image2.jpg

Then the same URL without the subfolder's name:

1. mywebsite.com/uploads/image.jpg
2. mywebsite.com/uploads/image2.jpg

**INFO:** I can only use `.htaccess` to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rules in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^uploads\/image\.jpg$ /wp-contents/uploads/2019/02/image.jpg [L]
RewriteRule ^uploads\/image2\.jpg$ /wp-contents/uploads/user/demo/2019/02/image2.jpg [L]
```

another rule for all /uploads/image***.jpg to /wp-contents/uploads/2019/02/image***.jpg

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^uploads\/(.*)$ /wp-contents/uploads/2019/02/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you, But I have a lot of subfolders, I can do that for all the images in the folder?. without writing  static subfolders / images names

Comment: Yes, but if you have all links as example /uploads/image***.jpg the destination folder should be the same... not one is /wp-contents/uploads/2019/02/image***.jpg and another /wp-contents/uploads/user/demo/2019/02/image***.jpg